# How to check for and remove a photo from an iPhoto album using AppleScript

Tags: applescript, iphoto

I want to write an AppleScript to import a photo into an album. If a photo with the same file-name already exists in the given album, I want to remove the existing one first, then proceed with the import. I tried:

```
if album "MyAlbum" contains "pic1.jpg" then
    remove "pic1.jpg" from album "MyAlbum"
end if
```

but that doesn't compile.  (I know how to do the actual import part.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out the answer is really simple:

```
remove (every photo of album "MyAlbum" whose image filename is "pic1.jpg")
```